# "Variable does not exist" Error While Reference a Package Namespace

Tags: apex, managed-package, compile-error

## Solved?

The root cause is my inaccuracy in object initiating: i just forgot to add `new`.

But the misleading error message is still in place. So other APEX devs may hit the same issue.

## Initial Question

It's a bit strange thing i hit, but since i am not very experienced APEX dev yet... Please give me an idea what's wrong below?

I am coding a custom code which is going to force sync our customer data from SFDC to Zendesk. So i installed [a managed package](https://github.com/JmeG/Force.com-Toolkit-for-Zendesk) which should do all the Zendesk API work. The package's namespace prefix is `zdapiv1`.

This code which uses the prefix compiles like a charm:

```
@isTest

global with sharing class ZdSyncOrg {
    private static zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection zconn;

    private static zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection getConnection() {
        if (null == zconn) {
            zconn = zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection.createWithAPIToken('subdomain','email@example.com','token');
        }
        return zconn;
    }

    @isTest static void testGetConnection() {
        zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection conn = getConnection();
        System.assertNotEquals(null, conn);
        System.assertEquals(conn, zconn);
    }
}
```

But when i add another method i see `[OPERATION FAILED]: classes/ZdSyncOrg.cls: Variable does not exist: zdapiv1 (Line: 23, Column: 22)`.

Here is the example:

```
@isTest

global with sharing class ZdSyncOrg {
    private static zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection zconn;
    private static zdapiv1.ZendeskOrganizationsAPI orgApi;

    private static zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection getConnection() {
        if (null == zconn) {
            zconn = zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection.createWithAPIToken('subdomain','email@example.com','token');
        }
        return zconn;
    }

    @isTest static void testGetConnection() {
        zdapiv1.ZendeskConnection conn = getConnection();
        System.assertNotEquals(null, conn);
        System.assertEquals(conn, zconn);
    }

    private static zdapiv1.ZendeskOrganizationsAPI getOrgApi() {
        if (null == orgApi) {
            // The error points to the following line:
            orgApi = zdapiv1.ZendeskOrganizationsAPI(getConnection());
        }
        return orgApi;
    }
}
```

That puzzles me a lot. Why the same namespace prefix cannot be used in the other method? And how to work that around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Github code "ZendeskOrganizationsAPI" does not have static methods .You will have to use an Instance of the class and use constructors designed in the class

```
private static zdapiv1.ZendeskOrganizationsAPI getOrgApi() {
    if (null == orgApi) {
        // The corrected line
        zdapiv1.ZendeskOrganizationsAPI orgApi = new zdapiv1.ZendeskOrganizationsAPI(getConnection());
    }
    return orgApi;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if it had static methods, because OP is trying to call the class itself as a static method. That said, your correction should work just fine.

Comment: Exactly, the problem has not so much to do with static methods, but more with the lack of the `new` keyword.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you! the problem seems in the confusing error message which is totally misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to read [Type Resolution and System Namespace for Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_type_resolution.htm) for more details, but the short version is that Salesforce goes through a few possible combinations of places to look for a type, and returns that rather cryptic error message if the algorithm fails to find a suitable data type.

Since you were trying to call a reference to a method, it first looked for a local variable, then a static variable, then your local classes. Even though the namespace was correct, custom namespaces don't contain methods, so it gave up.

By reading the document I linked here, and understanding how type resolution works, you'll be better prepared to fix this error in the future.